# The tableview row cannot be load correctly

Tags: ios, uitableview

The UITableView row cannot be loaded after row 13. The data reload from 0 again.
i found out that the row is loaded until 13. And the row will start again from beginning.

If I set the height of each row to 20. All the row can be loaded in one screen then everything fine.

but I need to set the height to 40. then it has the problem.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"GroupsCell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    NSLog(@"test indexpath = %ld",(long)indexPath.row);
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
}
if(indexPath.row == 0){
    UIImageView *profileImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 10, 80.0, 80.0)];
    NSString *url = [[NSString alloc] init];
    NSString *tempurl =self.iconimgpath;
    NSLog(@"tempurl = %@",tempurl);
    url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",tempurl];
    NSURL * imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
    profileImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    [profileImageView sd_setImageWithURL:imageURL placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"loadinglogo.png"]];

    profileImageView.tag = 11;
    if([cell.contentView viewWithTag:11])
        [[cell.contentView viewWithTag:11] removeFromSuperview];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:profileImageView];
    //[cell.contentView addSubview:profileImageView];



}
else{
        if(_feedItems.count>0 && (indexPath.row > 0))
            {

                UILabel * groupnamelabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 15.0, 300,20)];
                groupnamelabel.text = [_feedItems[indexPath.row-1] groupname];
                //groupnamelabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"TrebuchetMS-Bold" size:18];
                groupnamelabel.tag = 99;
                if([cell.contentView viewWithTag:99]){
                    [[cell.contentView viewWithTag:99] removeFromSuperview];
                }
                [groupnamelabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15]];
                [cell.contentView addSubview:groupnamelabel];


                    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(pushAction:)];
                    [groupnamelabel addGestureRecognizer:tap];
                    groupnamelabel.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

            }
    }

return cell;
```

I found out the problem is

```
self.MyGrouptableview = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,65,screenWidth,screenHeight-150) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
```

If I set the height of the tableview long enough everything would be alright but the user cannot scroll to the bottom.

Comment: The fundamental problem is that cells are reused. If you're going to use this old-school technique (not specifying prototype cell in storyboard or registering class or NIB with the identifier), you should only add controls if `cell` was `nil`. Right now, when a cell is re-used, you're adding more and more controls to the cell. So, if `cell` was `nil`, create the controls and set their tags, and the code after that should only update the controls. Also, you probably want two different cell identifiers for your two types of cells given that each has its own type of controls.

Comment: Frankly, it's not clear to me why you don't use the built-in image view and label that `UITableViewCell` provides. And if you're customizing, why you wouldn't use storyboard cell prototype (probably easiest) or NIB or custom class. Is there a reason you're doing it this way?